# Как задать курсив для телеграм бота

Tags: python, шрифты, telegram, telebot

Столкнулся с проблемой невозможности добавления жирности и курсива в сообщениях моего бота.
Собственно, вот кусок кода, в котором я отправляю сообщение пользователю:
`bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '__Ваше фото обрабатывается...__')`
Однако эта фраза не становится курсивом, а эти педали остаются.
Хотя если человек сам напишет любую фразу, начав с двух педалей и закончив двумя педалями, то его сообщение станет курсивным, а педали пропадут.

Comment: Педаль? :D Символ нижнего подчеркивания, же

Comment: когда-то я услышал этот термин от моего старого знакомого программиста, вот и понравилось)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать [send_message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) параметр `parse_mode`:

```
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '__Ваше фото обрабатывается...__', parse_mode="Markdown")
```

Answer (score 0):

text = ***Ваше фото обрабатывается...***

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown", parse_mode=telegram.ParseMode.HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Вместо двойных подчеркиваний и звездочек используй по одному